# Clicking on Notification Area Network Icon blocks TcpClient from receiving data

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tcpclient

I'm developing a real time charting application using Windows Forms .NET 4.5 . For receiving data from a server, I'm using a System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient object, which asynchronously receives data from the server after connection is established.

For some strange reason, the data reception is slowed down for 6 to 8 seconds when the Network icon in the Notification Area (which tells you the list of wifi networks etc.) is clicked. The data reception speed goes back to normal after 6 to 8 seconds. No exceptions are generated during this delay phase as far as I know.

This is the code for receiving data:

```
NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
try
{
    while (tcpClient.Available > 0) //Data available to be read
    {
       //byte[] data = new byte[500];
       int receiveChunkCount = 256; //receiveChunkOut = sendChunkCount in patient code
       byte[] data = new byte[receiveChunkCount];
       int bytesRead = 0, chunkSize = 1;

       while (bytesRead < data.Length)
             bytesRead += chunkSize = await stream.ReadAsync(data, bytesRead, data.Length - bytesRead);

       if (TcpDataReceived != null)
          TcpDataReceived(this, new TcpDataReceivedEventArgs(data));
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
   if (stream != null)
      stream.Dispose();
}
```

Any ideas for why this might be happening? It would be helpful just to know what might be occuring when the Network icon in the Notification area is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the reason for this occurrence was that there was a long-running loop in the part of the code which checked for the internet and server connection state. The long-running loop was completely utilizing the CPU when the Network Connection Status was checked using the Notification area icon, resulting in no processing power being left to display the Form components.

Changing that code to be asynchronous and avoiding loops altogether solved this issue.